# expo-av error: FATAL PLAYER ERROR: Player error: null

Tags: expo, http-live-streaming, expo-av

I am trying to play a online streaming in my mobile expo app, I used the [expo-av Video docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/#shouldcorrectpitch) and this [github gist snippet](https://gist.github.com/lucky-c/91d96977f913d54f723b64c34ce03fac) to create the following code:

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Video, ResizeMode } from 'expo-av';

/* Components */
import Container from './Container';

export default function LiveTv(props) {
  const { url, theme } = props;

  const colors = StyleSheet.create({
  });

  const video = useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState({});

  const playbackStatusUpdate = status => {
    if (status.error) {
      console.log(`FATAL PLAYER ERROR: ${status.error}`);
    }

    setStatus(() => status)
  };

  return (
    <Video ref={video} style={styles.media} source={{uri: "https://cdn.jmvstream.com/w/AVJ-14849/playlist/playlist.m3u8"}} onPlaybackStatusUpdate={playbackStatusUpdate} resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN} useNativeControls />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  media: {
    width: "100%",
    height: undefined,
    aspectRatio: 16/9,

    borderRadius: 10,
  },
});
```

The problem is that it works for a certain amount of time, them I got the error `FATAL PLAYER ERROR: Player error: null` and the player just disappear

I tried to run this same code with a .mp4 online video file and it works just right
Even with the url provided in the github snippet ("http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8") it worked, it might be a problem with my url, but i have tested it with a hls tester (https://players.akamai.com/players/hlsjs?streamUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.jmvstream.com%2Fw%2FAVJ-14849%2Fplaylist%2Fplaylist.m3u8) and its working, so I don't have any idea of what can be the problem and how to solve it